ffmpeg doesn't generate a ISO/IEC 14496-17 (MPEG-4 text) track when ingesting WebVTT subtitles to produce MPEGTS
We are trying to create a mpegts with an ISO/IEC 14496-17 (MPEG-4 text) subtitles track, using WebVTT, but seems like ffmpeg creates a ISO 13818-1 PES private data instead.
The following is the ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i subtitle.vtt -c:s mov_text -f mpegts output3GPP.ts
This is using the following subtitle.vtt file:
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:01.000
Subtitle 1

00:01.000 --> 00:02.000
Subtitle 2

00:02.000 --> 00:03.000
Subtitle 3

00:03.000 --> 00:04.000
Subtitle 4

And the following is the output of the ffprobe for that file:
Input #0, mpegts, from 'output3GPP.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:19.00, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Unsupported codec with id 98314 for input stream 0

However, if we generate an mp4, it works, the following is the command:
ffmpeg -i subtitle.vtt -c:s mov_text -f mp4 output3GPP.ts
And the following is the output of the ffprobe for that file:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output3GPP.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0
kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler

Any reason why both commands behave differently? is mpegts not supporting ISO/IEC 14496-17 (MPEG-4 text)?
